# Defining limits on geom_segment with data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to start by saying I have read this post and Brian Diggs gave some great help!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085518/13364594
I am still having trouble getting my geom_segment to stop at a value derived from my data set.

```
ggplot(Slate_ts,aes (Date, Q))+    
geom_line()+    
geom_segment(data= Slate_ts, xend=as.POSIXct("2019-03-21"),x=as.POSIXct("2019-03-21"),y= -Inf, yend= Q)
```

Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomSegment,  :    object 'Q' not found

If I swap the lower most Q for a value of 2 I get a graph:

[image: Slate creek hydrograph]

I know I missing something fundamental in the script.
Slate_ts data looks like this

1. Date         Q
2. 2018-10-4   .0018
3. 2018-10-5   .0027

Thank you r community in advance

Comment: As Q is a variable in your df you have to put it inside an `aes()` call. Try `geom_segment(data= Slate_ts, mapping = aes(yend= Q), xend=as.POSIXct("2019-03-21"),x=as.POSIXct("2019-03-21"), y= -Inf)`.

Comment: I have tried things similar to that, but the graph returns a vertical line with the upper boundary equal in height to the maximum value of Q of the df - from a completely different day.
Do I need to specify in the "aes(yend= Q)" script that I want the value of Q on "2019-03-21"?

Comment: Please include reproducible data using `dput()`, others can't help you if they can't see the data you have or run your code. See [here for tips on making R questions reproducible and including data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @NathanMack. As far as I got it you want a vertical line at date x = 2019-03-21 reaching up to the the `geom_line`. Simply filter the data used in geom_segement for this date. Try `geom_segment(data= filter(Slate_ts, Date == as.POSIXct("2019-03-21")), mapping = aes(yend= Q, xend = Date, x = Date, y= -Inf))`

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the concept of filtering by date.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ggplot2::economics` dataset as example data this can be achieved like so. Inside `geom_segement` simply filter your data for the date where you want to draw the vertical line. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(economics, aes (date, uempmed))+    
  geom_line() +    
  geom_segment(data = filter(economics, date == as.Date("1995-10-01")), mapping = aes(xend = date, x = date, y = -Inf, yend = uempmed), color = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>